# is SPWeb.GetUsageData still available

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, usage-counters

`SPWeb.GetUsageData` has been [around since Windows SharePoint Services 3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455850(v=office.12).aspx). In 2010 `SPWeb.GetUsageData` still yielded results. However, I have not found a single SharePoint installation either 2013 or 2016 in which `SPWeb.GetUsageData` returned anything other than `null`.

I know that ["Web Analytics in SharePoint Server 2010" is discontinued](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742.aspx#section1).
However it is my understanding that [`SPWeb.GetUsageData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455850(v=office.15).aspx) relies on the ["Usage and Health Data Collection service application"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15468.sharepoint-2013-how-to-choose-between-web-analytics-and-google-analytics.aspx) - which is configured and available in all the farms I checked. The needed [TimerJobs ("Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" and "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing")](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx) are disabled on most farms I check, but even enabling them will not make usage-data available.

On one side the [`SPWeb.GetUsageData` help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms455850(v=office.15).aspx) says "gets a table that contains information about the usage of a website..." it says nothing about it being no longer supported.. But on the other side in the `...\15\template\layouts\usagedetails.aspx` (the page that would show the contents of `SPWeb.GetUsageData`) the table called `UsageReportGridView` is wrapped inside a `<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">` so it will never show in SharePoint 2013/2016..

So my question is this: Are the "old" (i.e. pre-2010) usage-data informations still supported in 2013/2016?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having discussed this with Microsoft this is the not-so-offical answer:

> The 2010 method SPWeb.GetUsageData() is deprecated in SharePoint 2013.
>
> As a workaround the customer could get the data by directly going to SQL:
>   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715694(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN its supported in SP2013 on-premise, there is no mention of SP2016 (so i assume its not available in SP2016).

[image: SPWeb.GetUsageData]

the code that i have used to get this done

```
  SPWeb oWeb = new SPSite("http://sername/sites/test").RootWeb;  

            //SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;   

            DataTable dt = oWeb.GetUsageData(Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsageReportType.user, Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUsagePeriodType.day);   

            datagrid1.DataSource = dt;  

            datagrid1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Did you try this? I mean I know how it works... The method still exists in the 2016 code-base. Have you found **any SP2013 in which GetUsageData yields any result besides null**?

Comment: Yes it works in SP2013

Comment: Interesting. How did you get it to work?

Comment: yesterday i tried to execute a powershell for the same on  SP2013 environment but i am surprised i don't get any data now as a workaround i found this blog though https://briantjackett.com/2013/08/26/powershell-script-to-workaround-no-data-in-sharepoint-2013-usage-reports/

Comment: I have read that article, however it's talking about empty excel-reports and they do not depend on `SPWeb.GetUsageData`. Anyhow - I have tested what the article describes and the receivers in question are present in all my farms. So no - that is no explanation.

Comment: Have you managed to re-test? Can you confirm SPWeb.GetUsageData returning data?

Comment: yes i did try but no results, I am not sure if Web analytics database is configured in environment where i executed my script. It was migrated from SP2010 to SP2013 i think after migration i never tested it again. Right now, I can't play with settings there as its a live environment .

Comment: That's rather sad. However, WebAnalytics-DB ist not used in this scenario. SPWeb.GetUsageData utilizes the Usage-DB.